# Wordlist generation for password recovery

Tags: password-recovery

I'm trying to build a wordlist to recover a password to a file.  I know what the password consisted of, but not which order the components were in.

How would I go about building a wordlist out of discrete components?

For example, not the actual phrases, but

> 1964 red Ford Mustang !

It would be some variation of those, but the ! would not be in the middle of any of the words.

I tried doing this with crunch but it seems I'm not understanding the -p parameter.

Comment: https://github.com/topics/password-cracker?l=python  might be helpful

Comment: There is `/var/dict/words`. What you're attempting is called "password cracking". Research in this area, and creating cracking tools, has been going on for decades (I checked for "Joe" entries (passwd==userid) in NIS in 1986). Please search for "password cracking" using your favorite search engine. Any program you write will not be as "good" as the existing tools.

Comment: @Rinzwind Why restrict the github search with `l=python`? A password cracked by C is just as cracked as a password cracked by Python. With `l=python`, the search returns 129 entries, 294 entries without.

Comment: I've done some searching on the password cracking.  Does anyone have an example of how to do this with crunch? I have John the ripper set up, but I have to make the dictionary first.